# How would i make an invisible, clickable and accessible button that can be accessed through tab and enter/space keys?

Tags: html, css, button, accessibility

this is the code for a button that is currently operating

```
<a class="ng-click" ng-show="hasSuperUserAccess && !siteIsBeingEdited" class="addRowSite" ng-click="addSite()">
    {{ 'SiteManager_AddSite'|translate }}
</a>
```

Comment: Your question is missing the necessary information to give a proper answer. What kind of code is it? Where is the surrounding code? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: The code is html and my main goal is for an accessible use to be able to tab through to the "link" (which opens up a table on the page when clicked) and press either enter or space to open it. this is for a small contribution to the page "piwik"in order to make it more accessaible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `style="font-size:0px;"` to the  tag. This sets the font size to 0 pixels, rendering the link invisible but still usable via Tab and Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kL0wm6yd/

```
#link-name {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will hide the element from the page, you cannot click on it, but using tab you'll be able to select it and use enter to 'click' it. It also still occupies space on the page (which is why you can tab/enter).

I used the fiddle to denote first line and last line, so you can see that the link is still taking up space, however it is not visible. (you can't use tab in jsfiddle so just upload that code to your page and it will work. Any more questions just comment here.